# Specifying Order in Which Resources are Bundled

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails

Using the Resources plugin with my grails app, I have the following:

```
modules = {

  core {
    resource url: 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', linkOverride: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js', disposition: 'head'
    resource url: 'lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', linkOverride: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
    resource url: 'lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', linkOverride: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    resource url: 'js/main.js'
    resource url: 'css/main.css', disposition: 'head'
  }

  projectBids {
    dependsOn 'core'
    resource url: 'js/projectBid/script.js'
    resource url: 'css/projectBid/styles.css', disposition: 'head'
  }
}
```

And then in my GSP:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name='layout' content='main'/>
  <title>create project bid</title>
  <r:require modules="projectBids"/>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

In my css/projectBid/styles.css I am overriding a few of the bootstrap styles for a specific use case.  However, it would seem that the bootstrap css is being loaded last because it is taking precedence on the styles.

Is there a way I can make sure one resource is loaded before/after another between modules?